# How to set a SCSS variable using angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

i am trying to change a css variable using a component but for some reason it doesn't work, any help ?

```
//work but i dont want to use the property background
<div class="planete" [ngStyle]="{'background': planete.planeteBackgroundColor }"></div> 

/* this is what i'd like to do :
.SCSS 
$my-var 
/*...*/
background: $my-var;
```

HTLM:

```
// does not work
<div class="planete" [ngStyle]="{'$my-var': planete.planeteBackgroundColor }">

// second option:
.SCSS 
--my-var 
/*...*/
background: var(--my-var)
```

HTLM:

```
// does not work
<div class="planete" [ngStyle]="{'--my-var': planete.planeteBackgroundColor }">
```

Thanks for the reply

Comment: You can’t do this with ngStyle I’m afraid. There are other ways though: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/build-truly-dynamic-theme-with-css-variables-539516e95837

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
  <div class="planete" [ngStyle]="{'background': var(planeteBackgroundColor) }">
```

.SCSS

```
planeteBackgroundColor='FFFFFF'
```

But the easieast way to build dynamic theme should be:

```
 <div class="planete" [ngStyle]="{'background': planeteBackgroundColor }">
```

and define variable in your component ts file:

```
planeteBackgroundColor='FFFFFF'
```

Comment: i want to use a scc variable for the background color because it is embeded in a radial-gradient function in my css file. 
But thanks to MikeOne i resolved this like this :
In component ts :
  setColor(){
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('$planete-color',this.planete.planeteBackgroundColor);
  }
in scss file :
$planete-background-color : var(--planete-color);

Comment: but i face an other problem, it is not allowed when i passe the variable, in an other variable :
 '@'include border-gradient($planete-background-color, $planete-border-color);
/* ** */
'@'mixin border-gradient($from, $to, $weight: 0, $blur-radius:0, $spread-radius:0)

that is not working